# radius of convergence of a power series unable to solver

Tags: power-series

Question:

Suppose a power series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
Satisfies
$$a_{n-2} + (n^2 + \alpha^2)a_n =0,\ for\ all\ n\geqslant 2$$ 
What is the radius of convergence of the power series?

I have tried:

1) Split into 2, odds and even

2) $$a_{0} + (n^2 + \alpha^2)a_2=0$$
 $$a_{1} + (n^2 + \alpha^2)a_3=0$$
3)$$a_{0} + (n^2 + \alpha^2)a_2=a_{1} + (n^2 + \alpha^2)a_3 $$
4) $$\frac {a_0-a_1}{a_3-a_0} = (n^2 + \alpha^2)$$
5) I am stuck here , I don't know whether this approach is correct.

Comment: Have you considered $x^2S(x)+\alpha^2S(x)$ ?

Comment: what does S(x) mean??

Comment: @winson it means your serie

Comment: I will say conserve the idea of "@zwim , but may use : $x^2S'(x)+\alpha^2S(x)$ and find an equation.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking a bit about it, I think there is simpler.

We have $|a_{n-2}| =(n^2+\alpha^2)|a_n|\ge n^2|a_n|$ thus $|a_n|\le \frac 1{n^2}|a_{n-2}|\le \dfrac{|a_{n\bmod 2}|}{(n!!)^2}$

If we take $M=\max(|a_0|,|a_1|)$ we have $|a_n|\le \dfrac{M}{(n!!)^2}$ and this gives absolute convergence with an infinite radius

In fact $\alpha$ is just a disturbance here, $a_n\to 0$ fast enough with the division by $n^2$ each step.